# How do I set a date field to null in Loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a model with 2 date fields defined, tied to a postgresql database.

I am exposing my model over a RESTful API.

I want to clear one of the date fields, i.e. set it to NULL over the API.
when I call put on the API, I cannot find any value for the date field that sets the date value to NULL - I only get a runtime error in loopback-datasource-juggler/lib/model-builder.js line 512.

Is this a bug or unsupported feature in loopback or is there a specific format for setting a date field to NULL.

thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Node API, you can do it with updateAttribute function :

```
module.exports = function(yourModel){
  yourModel.observe('after save', function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.instance.updateAttribute(
      "dateOne",
      null,
      function(err, obj){
        if (err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(obj);
      }
    );
    next();
  }
}
```

http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-prototype-updateattribute

Pay attention to different parameter types between updateAttribute and updateAttributes.

If you want to use API to update your model using PUT method, you have to pass object with null value of attribute. Use API Explorer and try PUT method of your model with passing your JSON data like this

```
{
   "dateOne": null,       
   "dateTwo": "2015-05-10T22:00:00.000Z",       
   "id": 1
 }
```

This will set your date to null.

Comment: I am seeing inconsistent behavior. When I do this in my test script (using frisby + jasmine), the null date causes a runtime error in my server. when I do it from the API explorer, it works...

Comment: My guess is that you are sending null value surrounded with double quotes so it is treated as string. You should send null without quotes. If this is not the case, can you please provide part of your test script that causes problem?